# How do you say "My respects." in Japanese?

Tags: translation, meaning, words, anime

I was watching "Garo - Vanishing Line" and the main character says "My respects." but his romanization it sounded similar to him saying "gosumpai" or something close to that. Nothing remotely close to "Watashi no sonkei".

Comment: Keep in mind that phrases in Japanese are not always going to be 1:1 direct translations to their counterparts in English. That being said, can you provide more context? Maybe a link to an audio/video clip?

Answer (score 4):

If this is what you heard around 0:09 (even in another episode), the answer is clear.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cv8NWiHJ6t0

The line is 「ご参拝{さんぱい}」, which means "***worshipping***", "***a visit to a shrine***", etc.  In the video above, he pronounces it like 「ごさんぱ～～い」.

The subtitles there surely read "Mt respects.", but no one in real life would say 「ご参拝」 to greet a girl in Japanese (nor "My respect" in English).

Not being familiar with this anime, I just could not tell why the guy would use such an unusual phrase as a greeting, but I guess that is observed a lot in manga/anime.  The characters tend to use weird phrases, sentence-endings, etc. as a kind of ***role language***.

It is perfectly fine to be an anime/manga fan, but you should know that real native speakers do not speak like anime characters.

Comment: Hmmm, yes, that is what I heard at 0:09 in the youtube link you provided. I was just confused as to why "My respects" was shown in the subtitles when he actually didn't say "My respects" so that made me want to know what "ごさんぱ～～い" really meant. That is what confused me, not the reality of speaking between anime and real fluent Japanese speakers.

Comment: Thank you for your help and shedding a little light on my misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

If it's "my respects" as in what you say to someone in condolence after a death, it could be ご愁傷様(でございます).

Respect is 尊敬 but to me, "my respects" is a phrase used in different circumstances, like condolence as mentioned. It might also be something like "pay my respects" to indicate a duty of some sort, like visiting someone.

So we need more information to help you.